# linking with my own glibc

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I want to do some modifications to glibc for learning purposes. However, I want to keep my original gcc settings intact. In other words, for usual compilation, I want to use the glibc currently in my system, but for some programs, I want to link my programs with my own modified glibc. How do I go writing a Makefile for such purpose?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `-nostdlib` option for GCC and link to your own library explicitly.  Read the notes on the man page for gcc carefully first.